# Exception has occurred: PermissionError

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to make a program with python that will be able to analyse some game event's statistics with OCR and make a summary of a player/group's performance. I'm really new to Python, and I had multiple Python (2 - 3) installed before because I was trying it a little bit years ago. So I uninstalled everything and reinstalled the latest Python 3 to the default/recommended installation (AppData) path.

```
def ocr_core(img):
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    return text
```

Error:

```
 Exception has occurred: PermissionError
[WinError 5] Access is denied
  File "G:\PythonProjects\NewWorldWarStats.py", line 7, in ocr_core
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "G:\PythonProjects\NewWorldWarStats.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(ocr_core(img))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

I'm trying pytesseract (same permission error with other OCR library) and cv2 to do the task but it gives me permission error no matter if I edit permission to that folder, run the Visual Studio Core as admin. I was also tried to run the project on other drives, nothing worked yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a sample img?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what was the problem. I had to put the whole "tesseract.exe" path, not just its main folder, altho most of the guides only put the folder, not the whole executable path.
So for me, this was the right one:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\Dany\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Thanks for the help.